# Problems installing "autovivification" module in Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl, autovivification

I have Strawberry Perl installed on my Windows 10 computer. I have been able to successfully install a number of CPAN modules, but I am getting stuck on the
[`autovivification`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification)
module.

It hangs on the `make test` part of the installation and I have to force it to quit. If I then try to run a program that uses `no autovivification` it fails with an error that it can't find the module in `@INC` which makes sense because it didn't install correctly.

I'm really not sure what to do next. Has anyone else had the same problem with installing this module on Strawberry Perl? What can be done about it?

Comment: Please run the tests manually so you can see where exactly it hangs. `perl -mCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->look('autovivification')"` ; `perl Makefile.PL` ; `gmake` ; `prove -bv`

Comment: @daxim: I think Strawberry uses `dmake`.

Comment: it ships with gmake and is configured to use it, check `%PERLROOT%\c\bin` and `perl -MConfig -E "say $Config{make}"`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure that this is really the best solution, but I think I just found a workaround for this problem. I simply skipped the make test part of the installation by opening the cpan shell, then doing: "notest install autovivification". That skipped the testing, so it wouldn't hang and it seemed to finish installing the module OK.  I briefly tested the package to see if it loaded, and it seems to have, but there's a chance that something could still be wrong. I'll update this post if I encounter a problem...

Comment: No, it's not the best solution. You need to check what the issue is with the tests. Run `cpan` to get the `cpan>` prompt and then do `look autovivication`. This will take you to a cmd prompt in a directory where the module has been downloaded and unpacked. Then you can create the Makefile with `perl Makefile.PL`, build the module with `dmake` and test it with `dmake test`. It should be obvious what the problem is. You can then `dmake install` to install the tested module if it passes.

Comment: tests should run in [verbose mode](http://p3rl.org/Test::Harness#HARNESS_VERBOSE)